# Is it possible to cast string into my own type?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, custom-type

```
public class Currency{
    private Code {get;set;}
    public Currency(string code){
      this.Code = code;
    }
    //more methods here
}
```

I want to be able to make my object castable

```
string curr = "USD";
Currency myType = (Currency)curr;
```

I know that I can do it with the contructor, but I have usecase where I need to cast without initializing the object...

I also believe that ill need a function like `FromString()` to do it
Thanks.

Comment: Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this method to your Currency class:

```
public static explicit operator Currency(String input) 
{
    return new Currency(input);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Currency cur = (Currency)"USD";
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just add an [explicit cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
public class Currency {
    private readonly string code;
    public string Code { get { return this.code; } }
    public Currency(string code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    //more methods here

    public static explicit operator Currency(string code) {
        return new Currency(code);
    }
}
```

Now you can say:

```
string curr = "USD";
Currency myType = (Currency)curr;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you create your own cast-operators for your type, you can make this possible.

check out the [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) and [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keywords.

(in this case, I'd prefer an explicit cast).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this operator does what you want (as part of your Currency class):

```
public static explicit operator Currency(stringvalue){
    return new Currency(value);
}
```